# Learning how to Read Errors and Debug Ruby - Test Errors while Running Code from Pragmatic Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the latest edition (3?) of the Pragmatic Ruby book to help me learn Ruby, and just did a tutorial about sending emails. I ran the tests that I just constructed and am seeing some errors. I'm trying to debug them without simply re-doing all the code I just did. Unfortunately, I'm not good enough at understanding the Rails setup to understand what these errors mean and what I should look for:

```
  1) Error:
test_order_received(NotifierTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: /PATH_BASE/agileRails/depot/app/views/notifier/order_received.text.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
..._buffer.safe_concat('Dear '); = @order.name ;@output_buffer....
...                               ^
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_view/template.rb:258:in `module_eval'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_view/template.rb:258:in `compile'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_view/template.rb:134:in `block in render'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `block in _render_template'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:115:in `_render_template'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `render_to_body'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:102:in `render_to_string'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:93:in `render'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/deprecated_api.rb:111:in `render'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:735:in `block in collect_responses_and_parts_order'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:750:in `each'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:750:in `block in each_template'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:745:in `each'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:745:in `each_template'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:731:in `collect_responses_and_parts_order'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:673:in `mail'
    /PATH_BASE/Dropbox/Development/instruction/agileRails/depot/app/mailers/notifier.rb:12:in `order_received'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/old_api.rb:75:in `process'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:471:in `process'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:466:in `initialize'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:450:in `new'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:450:in `method_missing'
    test/functional/notifier_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:NotifierTest>'

  2) Error:
test_order_shipped(NotifierTest):
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    /PATH_BASE/agileRails/depot/app/mailers/notifier.rb:20:in `order_shipped'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/old_api.rb:75:in `process'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:471:in `process'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:466:in `initialize'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:450:in `new'
    /PATH_BASE/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.0.9/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:450:in `method_missing'
    test/functional/notifier_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:NotifierTest>'
```

UPDATED to add the code for order_received.text.erb

```
Dear <% = @order.name %>

Thank you for your recent order from The Pragmatic Store.

You ordered the following items:
<%= render @order.line_items %>

We'll send you a separate e-mail when your order ships.
```

Comment: Are you referring to the book "programming ruby" or the book "agile web development with Rails"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important lines are these:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
..._buffer.safe_concat('Dear '); = @order.name ;@output_buffer....
...                               ^
```

That semicolon before the `=` shouldn't be there, or perhaps the `=` itself shouldn't be there :)

**Edit:** here's the problem:

```
<% = @order.name %>
```

should be

```
<%= @order.name %>
```

Comment: Is there a way to know what file I should concentrate on? I can't seem to find that particular line anywhere, I even did a search for semi-colons in my entire project and did not find that line.

Comment: It looks like it's in `PATH_BASE/agileRails/depot/app/views/notifier/order_received.text.erb`, as the output says.

Comment: I don't know if that's the case. I included the full text of that file in an updated version of question.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I never would have picked that up. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionView::Template::Error: /PATH_BASE/agileRails/depot/app/views/notifier/order_received.text.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
..._buffer.safe_concat('Dear '); = @order.name ;@output_buffer....
```

Generally, the most useful part of an error is at the top, Everything below that goes further into the backtrace.  in this example, the error says you are missing an end keyword, but I'd suggest removing the semi-colons.